# Office 365 API OutlookServicesClient Filter Messages Error

Tags: c#, odata, office365

I'm using OutlookServicesClient to get messages.
I'm trying to get only messages received after a certain date, but here's where I receive an error.

The code I use to get the mails and filter:

```
public async Task<IReadOnlyList<IMessage>> GetMails(DateTime? MailsAfterDate)
    {
        OutlookServicesClient oc = await _OutlookAuthentificationService.GetOutlookClient();

        if (oc != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var msgList = await oc.Me.Messages
                              .Expand(m => m.Attachments)
                              .Where(m => !m.DateTimeReceived.HasValue || !MailsAfterDate.HasValue || m.DateTimeReceived.Value.LocalDateTime.Ticks >= MailsAfterDate.Value.Ticks)
                              .ExecuteAsync();

                return msgList.CurrentPage;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The error: Cannot resolve the OData request URL.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found why this isn't working:
DateTimeReceived is a nullable datetime, but you cannot use the hasvalue of value property inside the where clause.

Without this the function works properly.